# In Wordpress, how can I make categories from WooCommerce products be separated by hyphens instead of commas?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvAkO.jpg)

As you can see in the image, the categories are displayed with commas, and I want to know if there is a way for it to be "Marita Lopera – Colección Ópera Prima". Thank you.

I can't see any custom options in the WooCommerce tab, so I'm wondering if there is additional code needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the below code and create a file meta.php at your-active-theme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php and paste the code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Meta
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package     WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version     3.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;
?>
<div class="product_meta">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start' ); ?>

    <?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) : ?>

        <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></span>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ' - ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

    <?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your answer. It changed the display of categories from commas to dashes but only when I'm inside the description of a single product. When I am seeing my products on the main store page, they are still separated by commas. Can you help me with that as well?